# Multiple GtkPaned within a ScrolledWindow do not increase scrollbar size

Tags: gtk, scrollbar, gtk3, pane

Here is a Glade file to show the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name gchararray1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">hjkrfdtrfewyujhgnbhfsfwqrethetyghgfdagfdsaf</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">rtejnheth</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">gfedjfdgvn ry,klitloiukytrgfadedsjhfdjmkiul,ou</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">ulkj;.io/fsbghnjmtkuiuytgafwasSvfbghnjur6ujtergfrafd</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">rfetgnhyetnt</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">grtfhbrehgewt</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">hgrewtghrw</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">gtrewhegytht</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">rtgehnjtehnjythnjey</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">rtgejhnythjye5r</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">ertwhrethert</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">wrthergthyegrt</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">gfedwgrwegrft</col>
      </row>
    </data>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkPaned" id="paned1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="position">440</property>
        <property name="position_set">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
            <property name="min_content_width">100</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkPaned" id="paned3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow3">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
                        <property name="min_content_width">100</property>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <property name="model">liststore1</property>
                            <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
                            <child internal-child="selection">
                              <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection1"/>
                            </child>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
                                <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                                <child>
                                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext1">
                                    <property name="ellipsize">middle</property>
                                  </object>
                                  <attributes>
                                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                                  </attributes>
                                </child>
                              </object>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                        </child>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="resize">False</property>
                        <property name="shrink">False</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkPaned" id="paned4">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow4">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
                            <property name="min_content_width">100</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview2">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="model">liststore1</property>
                                <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
                                <property name="search_column">0</property>
                                <child internal-child="selection">
                                  <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection3"/>
                                </child>
                                <child>
                                  <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn2">
                                    <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                                    <child>
                                      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext2">
                                        <property name="ellipsize">middle</property>
                                      </object>
                                      <attributes>
                                        <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                                      </attributes>
                                    </child>
                                  </object>
                                </child>
                              </object>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                          <packing>
                            <property name="resize">False</property>
                            <property name="shrink">False</property>
                          </packing>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkPaned" id="paned5">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow5">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
                                <property name="min_content_width">100</property>
                                <child>
                                  <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview3">
                                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                    <property name="model">liststore1</property>
                                    <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
                                    <property name="search_column">0</property>
                                    <child internal-child="selection">
                                      <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection4"/>
                                    </child>
                                    <child>
                                      <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn3">
                                        <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                                        <child>
                                          <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext3">
                                            <property name="ellipsize">middle</property>
                                          </object>
                                          <attributes>
                                            <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                                          </attributes>
                                        </child>
                                      </object>
                                    </child>
                                  </object>
                                </child>
                              </object>
                              <packing>
                                <property name="resize">False</property>
                                <property name="shrink">False</property>
                              </packing>
                            </child>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow6">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
                                <property name="min_content_width">100</property>
                                <child>
                                  <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview4">
                                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                    <property name="model">liststore1</property>
                                    <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
                                    <property name="search_column">0</property>
                                    <child internal-child="selection">
                                      <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection5"/>
                                    </child>
                                    <child>
                                      <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn4">
                                        <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                                        <child>
                                          <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext4">
                                            <property name="ellipsize">middle</property>
                                          </object>
                                          <attributes>
                                            <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                                          </attributes>
                                        </child>
                                      </object>
                                    </child>
                                  </object>
                                </child>
                              </object>
                              <packing>
                                <property name="resize">False</property>
                                <property name="shrink">False</property>
                              </packing>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                          <packing>
                            <property name="resize">True</property>
                            <property name="shrink">False</property>
                          </packing>
                        </child>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="resize">True</property>
                        <property name="shrink">False</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">True</property>
            <property name="shrink">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
                <property name="width_request">20</property>
                <property name="height_request">20</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">False</property>
            <property name="shrink">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

More info: I am trying to make a mockup of a [Miller Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) file browser.

I am pretty happy with my creation, except for the problem that the scrolled window gets priority. I want the panes to have priority, so that the user can increase the width of a pane, which will in turn increase the overall width of the scrolled window.

I thought of implementing something like 'ScrolledWindow property set width', but I am not finding any information like that. Or how to detect the paned bar being maxed out.